# Publish NodeJS Server Online

Tags: node.js, port

I'm currently having an issue when trying to port forward my modem to my Node.js server. Sorry if this is a duplicate question, i've spent some time looking at familiar topics.

I'm using the express framework, I've included a small snippet, so you can see what port the node.js server is listening too.

(**Quick Question:** Do I use server.listen or app.listen in this situation? What's the difference?)

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);

app.listen(4000);
```

I've also attatched a picture containing:

- The node.js server running.
- ipconfig (so you can see my local IP address)
- and a screenshot of my modems' port forward settings.

[image: Modem Port Forwarding]

When I google "Whats my IP Address" and retrieve my public IP address, then navigate to it I receive an error on my browser stating that the server took to long to respond. I assume the server isn't being port forwarded, however I can't seem to isolate the issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your modem/wifi router's public IP address keeps changing frequently every now and then or when your router reboots.  This is because of DHCP.

Port forwarding and hacking your wifi router firewall rules to allow public access to your home or office network is an unsafe practice.

That's where simple tools like SocketXP come in handy.  SocketXP will provide you a public URL to access your NodeJS server running in your localhost machine like your home/office laptop or server.

Here is a great blog article on [how to install and setup SocketXP to access your local NodeJS server](https://www.socketxp.com/blog/public-url-nodejs-app/) from the internet.

Answer (score 0):

If you're wrapping your Express app in a `http` **server**, you should listen on it like so `server.listen(4000)`.

Also make sure that your **firewall** on your computer is not blocking access to that port. A good alternative to the port forwarding + disabling firewall rules is to use a reverse proxy, something like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com) for example

Comment: I've looked into alternatives such as ngrok, localtunnel.me, now.sh, I was just curious on how to port forward the node js server over the modem. I'm sure I configured it appropriately so I can't really find what's wrong with it. =|

Comment: Got you. As I said, make sure your server is responding by calling it locally from your machine. Then make sure your Firewall is not blocking it